# How to get point index of SelectionStart in databound array of - MS Charts

Tags: c#, mschart

What I do really need is retrieving the precise zero-based index in the databound array to a MS Chart control (of the selection "SelectionStart" and "SelectionEnd"). The properties I can find do hold the "double" values and not indices:

```
double dStart = chrt.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SelectionStart;
```

I need something like this code :

```
int indexInArray = chrt.ChartAreas[0].CursorX.SelectedIndex;
```

Comment: do you know `IndexOf()` method ?,maybe you can try to work around on that.

Comment: Dear Niang, could you please explain how to use the `IndexOf()` method? Thanks.